# Как отключить tab TabLayout

Tags: android

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы не нажималась средняя кнопка. Я использую TabLayout

Comment: disable пробовали?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб disable не нашел. Для TabItem в xml нет параметра enable иначе бы все быол бы просто

Comment: значит надо лезть в сорцы и смотреть.
но выглядеть должно примерно вот так `((ViewGroup)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setEnable(false)`
Только проверок всяких добавьте, а то может чего-то и не быть

Comment: @andreich, а через xml ни как?

Comment: думаю что никак

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как полностью отключить tabLayout (если необходимо отключить лишь 1 tab, то вместо цикла используйте конкретный индекс)

Вариант 1:

```
LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0));
   for(int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
       tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               return true;
           }
       });
   }
```

Вариант 2:

```
LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
tabStrip.setEnabled(false);
for(int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
       tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setClickable(false);
}
```

Для kotlin:

```
val tabs: LinearLayout = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
tabs.isEnabled = false
for( i in 0 .. tabs.getChildCount){
tabs.getChildAt(i)?.isClickable = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

значит надо лезть в сорцы и смотреть. но выглядеть должно примерно вот так ((ViewGroup)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setEnable‌​(false) Только проверок всяких добавьте, а то может чего-то и не быть